# Only redirect the parent folder and not sub folder .htaccess

Tags: mod-rewrite

I am struggling with a redirect rule for the following scenario:

Parent folder/site (landing page)

/about/leaders

Sub sites (link to profile)

/about/leaders/name1
/about/leaders/name2

I need to deactivate the /about/leaders page and redirect to /
but, the profiles should still be online.

It must be similiar to this =

```
RedirectMatch 301 /about/leaders/(.*) /
RedirectMatch 301 /about/leaders(.*) /$1
```

But this doesn't work. On subprofiles, the part /about/leaders gets remove and only /nameX stays. I couldn't find an answer for that. Maybe other people would like to achieve something similiar.

Anyways, I am glad for every help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Greeings Jens,

Think you need one line of code

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/about/leaders/?$ /
```

I am anal about using anchors. So first anchor to leading portion of URL with `^`. Then you optionally match the trailing "/" with `?`. Then anchor that to tail end of URL via `$`. That should be it. No need for second directive.

Since the more extended URLs of `/about/leaders/name` do not match the pattern, they should be accessible as normal.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You might be better off using mod_rewrite. Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^about/leaders(/.*|)$ /$1 [L,R=302,NC]
```

Once you verify it is working fine, replace `R=302` to `R=301`. Avoid using `R=301` (Permanent Redirect) while testing your mod_rewrite rules.

Comment: Thanks, anubhava! But I went for the answer below (was less work to implement)

Comment: Sure that's your choice, just telling you that other answer is will not redirect URIs such as `/about/leaders` or `/about/leaders/abcd`